# How to reference other dataframe column values in mutate in r

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in r

```
  Date          hour_bucket   qpmnt_name     location  Blk  Cols 
  01-01-2017    0-1           501            1B12E3    1B   12 
  01-01-2017    1-1           501            1C13E3    1C   13 
  01-01-2017    1-2           501            1C14E3    1C   14
  01-01-2017    1-2           501            1D12E3    1D   12
```

I want to calculate on a specific date,hour bucket and eqpmnt_name how much distance traveled by that specific equipment.

I have a block to block distance dataframe

```
from_block    to_block    dist
   A             B         25
   B             C         5
   C             D         25
   D             E         5
```

Sample calculation.. e.g  on `01-01-2017` and hour bucket `1-2` and equipment name `501` distance travel would be `1C to 1D` now, I want to look up in distance dataframe for distance from `C to D` which is 25.

My desired dataframe would be

```
  Date          hour_bucket   qpmnt_name     Distance 
  01-01-2017    0-1           501            0 
  01-01-2017    1-1           501            0 
  01-01-2017    1-2           501            25
```

My Attempt

```
 df1 <- df%>%
    group_by(qpmnt_name,date,hour_bucket) %>%  
    mutate(distance = ifelse(block == lag(block),0,
                       ifelse(block != lag(block), # Map the value from other dataframe )
                       )) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Isn't the 0 in  `01-01-2017    1-1           501            0 ` supposed to be 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer question from `OP` as part of title. Yes, one can reference other data frames in `mutate` but before referencing basis of reference should be prepared. `joins` makes referencing easier and efficient.

The `df` contains information to reference to `df_block` but we need to prepare data in a way which `join` can accept.

@hpesoj626 has already provided an answer. My approach is in similar line but I tried simplify it a bit.

> The approach:
>
> 1. Create `from_block` and `to_block` based on `Blk` column in `df`.
> 2. Join both data frames by `from_block` and `to_block`
> 3. Summarise to get distance.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(qpmnt_name, Date, hour_bucket) %>%
  mutate(from_block = sub("\\d+","",Blk), 
         to_block = sub("\\d+","",lead(Blk))) %>%
  left_join(df_block, by = c("from_block", "to_block")) %>%
  summarise(Distance = sum(dist, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#  qpmnt_name       Date hour_bucket Distance
#1        501 01-01-2017         0-1        0
#2        501 01-01-2017         1-1        0
#3        501 01-01-2017         1-2       25
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Date          hour_bucket   qpmnt_name     location  Blk  Cols 
01-01-2017    0-1           501            1B12E3    1B   12 
01-01-2017    1-1           501            1C13E3    1C   13 
01-01-2017    1-2           501            1C14E3    1C   14
01-01-2017    1-2           501            1D12E3    1D   12", 
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

df_block <- read.table(text = 
"from_block    to_block    dist
A             B         25
B             C         5
C             D         25
D             E         5", 
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt at a solution. I used a left join instead.

```
library(tidyverse)

zz <- "Date          hour_bucket   qpmnt_name     location  Blk  Cols 
01-01-2017    0-1           501            1B12E3    1B   12 
01-01-2017    1-1           501            1C13E3    1C   13 
01-01-2017    1-2           501            1C14E3    1C   14
01-01-2017    1-2           501            1D12E3    1D   12"

yy <- "from_block    to_block    dist
   A             B         25
   B             C         5
   C             D         25
   D             E         5 "


df <- read.table(text=zz, header=T)
lookup <- read.table(text=yy, header=T)
lookup1 <- lookup %>%
  unite(b2b, from_block,to_block, sep="")

df %>%
  mutate(
    b2b = paste0(str_extract(lag(df$Blk), "[:alpha:]"), str_extract(df$Blk, "[:alpha:]"))
  ) %>%
  group_by(qpmnt_name,Date,hour_bucket) %>%
  mutate(b2b = b2b[Blk != lag(Blk)]) %>%
  left_join(lookup1, by="b2b") %>%
  mutate(dist = replace_na(dist, 0)) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(dist), sum)

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
# # Groups:   qpmnt_name, Date [?]
#   qpmnt_name Date       hour_bucket  dist
#        <int> <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>
# 1        501 01-01-2017 0-1            0.
# 2        501 01-01-2017 1-1            0.
# 3        501 01-01-2017 1-2           25.
```